# Separating unique values in a column into separate columns within the same dataframe

Tags: r

I have data in which total number of fruits consumed in 2010 and 2011 are listed. However at the moment, the totals for each year are joined at the bottom of the data frame. Instead I want the totals for each year listed in a new column.

My current data frame looks like this:

| Fruit | Total | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 863 | 2010 |
| Banana | 224 | 2010 |
| Orange | 455 | 2010 |
| Apple | 934 | 2011 |
| Banana | 453 | 2011 |
| Orange | 534 | 2011 |

However I want it to look like this instead:

| Fruit | 2010 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 863 | 934 |
| Banana | 224 | 453 |
| Orange | 455 | 534 |

I am trying to do this using R

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Data as image is particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Fruit",
  timevar = "Year"
)
```

gives

```
   Fruit Total.2010 Total.2011
1  Apple        863        934
2 Banana        224        453
3 Orange        455        534
```

#Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Orange"), Total = c(863L, 224L, 455L, 934L, 453L,
534L), Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to convert from long to wide format, which can be done in multiple ways.

One example is with using tidyr

By running the code below, you create a new DF_wide from your original wide dataframe should count the totals per year in separate columns.

```
library(tidyr)

DF_wide <- spread(DF_long, Year, Fruit, Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Total ~ Fruit + Year, df)
#        Year
#Fruit    2010 2011
#  Apple   863  934
#  Banana  224  453
#  Orange  455  534
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Fruit = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Orange"), Total = c(863L, 224L, 455L, 934L, 453L,
534L), Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```